# What eslint rule to prevent variable definition by exploding the object?

Tags: eslint

What eslint rule for this?

**Bad code:**

`const {bar} = foo;`

```
function Foo(props) {
  const {bar} = props;
}
```

**Good code:**

`const bar = foo.bar;`

```
function Foo({bar}){

}
```

Comment: I don't think there is one, not in the core ruleset at least. There's the reverse, [`prefer-destructuring`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring#top). You might have to look elsewhere for additional rules that implement it. FWIW allowing destructuring in params but not assignments seems a little inconsistent - if you were trying to avoid the unfamiliar syntax neither should be allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I understand the reasoning about where to allow destruction objects yet I need the rules for this exact pattern.

Answer (score 0):

So far I got these 2 rules to prevent variable declaration from the object and also to prevent payload of the function without the object:

```
'no-restricted-syntax': [
  'warn',
  {
    'selector': 'VariableDeclarator > ObjectPattern',
    'message': 'Can not declare variable by exploding the object.',
  },
  {
    'selector': 'FunctionDeclaration[params] > Identifier.params',
    'message': 'Function\'s payload must be sent with object.',
  },
],
```

While I'm still testing behaviour of these, i set it to "warn" level

There is great tool to explore AST while this `no-restricted-syntax` rule requires CSS like selector to select things in AST tree

https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/219f178851d23e46276c7d06460b3b31/d2fd2f8c435e1f3d997beefb4eee268ee2c9abd2